# LabVIEW with mccdaq's WEB-TC

Tags: labview

I am using LabVIEW to program a system that interfaces through a mccdaq(web tc).  I am wondering how I can (through code) turn on and off an LED with the push of a button.  I am able to use the DoutBit VI in order to make the LED blink with a push of a button, but not stay on.  I have tried using Dout instead of DoutBit, but I am being told that my port is configured for an alarm.  (Which it's not).

Comment: Have you tried using LabVIEW drivers/vis provided by mccdaq on their website  http://www.mccdaq.com/software.aspx ?

Comment: I have, but either the program doesn't interface with the web-tc, or needs a newer version of LabVIEW.  We are limited to LabVIEW 7.1 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out on my own.  I needed to configure the channel within LabVIEW and send the outgoing port to my Dout.  Then I was able to send the digital signal to my LED and keep it lit for a period of time.  I was able to turn it on and off by simply sending it a hex digit (binary conversion) for the ports that I wanted to enable / disable.  (For example if i wanted to enable ports one and two, the hex answer is 3 ("11" in binary).